# how to create an anchor function but hide the link button in the search bar in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I created a button in Elementor

[image: I created a button in Elementor]

I created a menu anchor in Elementor

[image: i created a menu anchor in Elementor]

[image: result link search bar]

The result is that the anchor works fine but I want to remove #layanan on the tesaja.com/#layanan link in the search engine bar to just tesaja.com and the anchor works. How to? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without a custom code. This is the default behaviour. You need something like the code from Shubham Verma's comment above

Answer (score -1):

Try this, replace `menu-class` with your actual class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Smooth scroll to section when menu item is clicked
    $(".menu-class").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sectionId = $(this).attr('href');
        #console.log(sectionId);
        var section = $(sectionId);
        if (section.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: section.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, where do I add the code? Is it a button or an anchor menu and in which part?

Comment: you need to add this js code in footer